# How to implement a heartbeat on Spring (Pure) Websockets?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, heartbeat

I have a Spring websocket handler (no stomp and not socketjs), I see in docs that the websocket implementation of Spring doesn't include a heartbeat method.

I cannot detect a client "gone away" disconnection by `handleTransportError` or `afterConnectionClosed` methods.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If you created handler, then you created - server part. The logic which handles requests from clients.

You could create some client code and sent test message from it.

From server side you will see how exactly it is processed by the logs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, but will be enought to send a message once every x seconds? Is there any specification by the websocket protocol? Thanks

Comment: @Tobia I am afraid that nothing like this exists by default. Also, for proper answer you have to share some details of your project with configuration.